# Initializing map and set class member variables to empty in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, coding-style, initialization, set

I have a C++ class with two member variables

```
std::map<int, Node*> a;
```

and

```
std::set<Node*> b;
```

A style checker used at my University requires all member variables to be initialized in the constructor of the class. How can these member variables `a` and `b` be initialized to empty in the constructor of the class they are in?

Comment: You've commented two answers with "this works, thanks". You should now accept one (in case of identical answers, usually the first one). ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this:

```
class A
{
  public :

  A() : s(),
        m()
  {
  }


  std::set< int > s;
  std::map< int, double > m;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

As both `std::set` and `std::map` have "user"-declared default constructors they will be initialized implicitly however you construct your class. You don't have to do anything special to conform with the "style" guide.

Comment: Thank you Charles. The problem here was that the style checking is done automatically as part of an automatic grading system and requires all member variables to be explicitly initialized.

Comment: @Marek Miettinen: Are you sure the style check doesn't only apply to POD-types? I've never seen a style guide insist on explicitly initializing things that have default constructors that would be used for implicit initialization in any case.

Comment: And if the style checker really requires that, it is broken, simple as that.

Comment: @CharlesBailey so just declaring a member variable of type map and not initializing it in any constructor will initialize the variable? In C#, the variable points to null unless its initialized explicitly using the `new` keyword. Thats not the case in C++?

Answer (score 3):

Like this `SomeClass::SomeClass() : a(), b() {}`?

Answer (score 0):

This check is performed by the g++ compiler, when the -Weffc++ warning option is applied.
See Item 4 ("Make sure that objects are initialized before they're used"
in Scott Meyers, Effective C++, Book for more information,
why it might be reasonable to initialize all members using the member initialization list.
Basically he suggests to do this consistently and prefer this over assignments inside 
constructor bodies.

Comment: How does this explain how to do so? The Effective C++ reference is good research material, but not quite an answer.

Comment: @peachykeen: You are right, this is rather a comment, than an answer to the initial question.