# Struct in a list doesn't work

Tags: c++

I have this code:

hpp:

```
 #include <list>
 using namespace std;

 class funcionario
 {
      public:
          struct Dia {
          int d;
          int h;
          int id;
          int tipo;
     };
     funcionario ();
     void eliminar(int dia, int hora);

     private:
         list<Dia> agenda;
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "myClass.hpp"

funcionario::funcionario(){
    agenda = list<Dia> ();
}

void funcionario::eliminar(int dia, int hora) {
    list<funcionario::Dia>::iterator it;
    it = agenda.begin();
    while(it != agenda.end() && (*it).d <= dia) {
        if((*it).d == dia && (*it).h == hora) {
            agenda.erase(it);
            return;
        }
        ++it;
    }
}
```

I get this compiling error:

```
  Funcionario.cpp: In constructor ‘funcionario::funcionario()’:
  Funcionario.cpp:5: error: cannot convert ‘std::list<funcionario::Dia, std::allocator<funcionario::Dia> >’ to ‘int’ in assignment
  Funcionario.cpp: In member function ‘void funcionario::eliminar(int, int)’:
  Funcionario.cpp:9: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘((funcionario*)this)->funcionario::agenda’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  Funcionario.cpp:10: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘((funcionario*)this)->funcionario::agenda’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  Funcionario.cpp:11: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘((funcionario*)this)->funcionario::agenda’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `using namespace std` in a header is a bad idea.

Comment: not the point of the question :), but I have no choice over that.

Comment: @GerardDiaz I suspect this is not your real code. Please post the code that exhibits the problem as it is.

Comment: There's a semicolon missing after the class definition. The ctor, `something()` and `doSomething` are not declared. Other than that the code compiles just fine.

Comment: @sftrabbit Not the original code, but it includes all the parts in the problem.

Comment: no, it doesn't. why don't you try the code before posting? :(

Comment: You forgot the `#` character before your include in the .cpp file.

Comment: You forgot to change both uses of `and` to `&&`.

Comment: @Casey solved, but and stills works

Comment: @GerardDiaz maybe as a custom extension to your compiler, but not to anyone who does not have said extension. The Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler does not recognize `and` unless you are coding in Visual Basic, in that case it is not C++, it is Visual Basic.

Comment: Given the code as it is now, copy-and-pasting it into Visual Studio 2010, it works. Please select an answer that best represents the correct solution to your problem.

Comment: @Casey stock gcc does, if i'm not mistaken. And I'm in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working on my computer, so may it be a compiler problem? Try with another compiler and tell us if it worked

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but the code just needs to be fleshed out a bit with complete function definitions.  I got this to compile:

```
#include <list>
class myClass
{
   public:
    myClass();
      struct myStruct {
          int myInfo;
      };
    void something();
    void doSomething(myStruct & ms);

   private:
       std::list<myStruct> myList;
};


myClass::myClass(){
    myList = list<myStruct> ();
}

void myClass::something() {
    std::list<myStruct>::iterator it;
    it = myList.begin();
    while(it != myList.end()) {
       doSomething(*it);
       ++it;
    }
}
```

Incidentally (or maybe directly relevant, not sure) - the copy-initialization of myList in myClass() is unnecessary, as others have stated.  The list<> default constructor will do the right thing, and more efficiently.

Comment: Your request is unreasonable.  I've given you a compiling sample, but you haven't provided all of yours.

Comment: I modified the post with the original code, I though it was easier to solve if I made it more clear. No need to be mean.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean - I'm trying to help you.  Your new sample has "and" where I think you want && (logical and operator).

Answer (score 0):

The initialization you're looking for is analogous to [Initializing map and set class member variables to empty in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344464/initializing-map-and-set-class-member-variables-to-empty-in-c) - but actually you'll get an empty list automatically (i.e. by the std::list default constructor).

Answer (score 0):

--Edited to reflect your posting of the original code--

`H` is not declared anywhere.

`and` is not a valid C++ keyword or token. Use `&&`.

Use the local header include form of : `#include "myClass.hpp"`

Comment: Modified the post with your suggestions, errors are the same.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I modified more the post.

Comment: @GerardDiaz It won't if you don't fix all the errors. See my comment(s) on your original post.